# Is there a way to have separate dev environments on one laptop

Tags: virtual-machine, version

I am setting up a new laptop and I am hoping to set up several different programming environments without getting them to step on each other.

My actual uses are varied, but let us take a specific example: I maintain python 2.7, and develop python 3.newest.

The full belt-and-suspenders solution would be to have a VirtualBox (or similar) for every system I work with, but is there a better way? (Do not be afraid of providing very obvious answers - I am a recent linux user, if there's something "everybody has heard of," there's a fair chance I haven't heard it.

For clarity - the separate environments I need are for various different versions of `gcc`, various versions of `clang`. two different versions of `go`, `python` as specified above, too many versions of `dotnet` (though it seems that one plays nice when installed in parallel), various versions of `node.js`, and I'm sure I'm missing something - at this point I'm only working in the newest versions of `zig` and `rust` - but who is to say what the future will bring? So I'd better get them their own environments anyway, just so I don't get things mixed up if that ever happens in the future.

Comment: Did you even search for that? A quick search for "multiple python environments" will provide lots of answers. You might want to start with this though: [Python virtual environments: A primer](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)

Comment: I don't need multiple python environments, I need multiple *everything* environments! A python specific solution is useless to me, that was just an example of the kind of thing I'm dealing with. Yes obviously I googled for "multiple dev environment" "docker versioning" "virtual machine development" and various other things but I didn't find anything good.

Comment: There's no way for us to guess what you mean. You might want to add that information to the question. I do not know of a silver bullet for your problem. You have `jenv` for example for java, ruby had one too (I don't remember now). For your *everything* you could use virtual machines, or docker or ... that's why the question expecting an answer for *everything* is way too broad, for this type of question/answer forum at least.

Comment: More appropriate for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com maybe?

Comment: Yes, or maybe stackoverflow. In any case I suggest you try to list all the environments you use or plan to use. Because *everything* includes COBOL and you might not want all the answers tied to the lowest common factor. Also note that other set of issues arise with multiple environments, for example shared libraries, just to mention one. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of solutions there; generally, almost any language environment can be configured (often through means of configuration files in proper locations or environment variables, e.g. Python's `$PYTHONPATH`) to search for modules in specific locations; same is true for Linux' mechanisms for looking for executables (`$PATH`) and libraries (`$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`); using an independent environment really just usually boils down to modifying a few environment variables.

In the case of Python, Python itself has methods for that (`python -m venv`), but there's also very might package/prefix managers (`conda`/`mamba`). The same is true for other languages (Rust's `cargo`'s crates, which is well-designed, JavaScript's `npm`, which is anything but, PHP's PEAR, …).

In case you need more isolation, *containers* are probably for you: a full operating system file system tree "embedded" in your normal tree with only what you explicitly share into that to exchange anything with the "main" OS.

All in all, there's *a lot* of different ways, and for most languages, there's specific tools to make your life easier. You will have to look things up on a language-by-language basis.

Comment: Containers sound like the kind of thing I'm looking for. Do you have a good link, or should I get googling?

Comment: well, if you've heard of docker or podman, these are containers. But really, these are quite the strongest option, and you'll not have fun navigating two different file systems if you're still new to dealing with one Linux :) So, really, start with the language-specific tools, these allow for much smoother integration.

Answer (score 1):

To add to marcus's answer, you can use nix or guix to declaratively setup environments as you asked, though there is a learning curve. I prefer to use nix. For more reading: https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/